# SQL: Selecting columns if data is present in them or not

Tags: sql

I have two tables in `DB2`: `customer` and `order`. Data present in them is:

customer:

```
customer_id first_name  last_name   city            state    zipcode
1           George      Washington  Mount Vernon    VA       22121
2           John        Adams       Quincy          MA       02169
3           Thomas      Jefferson   Charlottesville VA       22902
4           James       Madison     Orange          VA       22960
5           James       Monroe      Charlottesville VA       22902
```

order:

```
order_id    order_date  amount   customer_id
1           NA          NA          1
2           03/14/1760  $78.50      3
3           NA          NA          2
4           09/03/1790  $65.50      3
5           07/21/1795  $25.50      10
6           11/27/1787  $14.40      9
```

Using the below query to join the tables:

```
select first_name, last_name, order_date, amount
from customers c
inner join orders o
on c.customer_id = o.customer_id
```

which gives me:

```
first_name  last_name   order_date  order_amount
George      Washington  NA          NA
John        Adams       NA          NA
Thomas      Jefferson   03/14/1760  $78.50
Thomas      Jefferson   09/03/1790  $65.50
```

I want to fetch the records only for those where data is present otherwise not.

Expected O/P:

```
first_name  last_name   order_date  order_amount
Thomas      Jefferson   03/14/1760  $78.50
Thomas      Jefferson   09/03/1790  $65.50
```

How can I achieve the above result using SQL? Any help will be really helpful.

Comment: `and o.order_date <> NA and o.amount   <> NA `

Comment: append this to your query ` AND order_date <> 'NA' AND order_amount <> 'NA'`

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: That is silly really. Amounts should be stored as DECIMAL not VARCHAR. You can then store NULL to indicate an absence of amount. Likewise for dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's sample code to basically ignore null value or in your case is 'NA' for both order amount and order date column

```
select first_name, 
last_name, 
order_date, 
amount
from customers c
inner join orders o on c.customer_id = o.customer_id
WHERE (o.order_date <> 'NA' OR o.order_date IS NOT NULL) 
AND (o.order_amount <> 'NA' OR o.order_amount IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use This code:

```
select first_name, last_name, order_date, amount
from customers c
inner join orders o
on c.customer_id = o.customer_id
WHERE o.order_date IS NOT NULL AND o.order_amount IS NOT NULL
```